# Ejected 'Create-React-App' babel config issue

Tags: webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

In my ejected 'create-react-app' I installed `react-copy-to-clipboard` package and I encountered an error:

```
export class CopyToClipboard extends React.PureComponent {
>  7 |   static propTypes = {
     |                    ^
   8 |     text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   9 |     children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  10 |     onCopy: PropTypes.func,

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

Following the solutions I found online I installed following dependencies:

```
yarn add @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --dev
```

and edited both package.json section responsible for babel config:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
    ]
  },
```

and webpack.config.js as some people suggested although for most people it was unnecessary:

```
module: {
  strictExportPresence: true,
  rules: [
    {
      test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env',
          '@babel/react',{
            'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]
      }
    },
(...)
```

I tried changing both or one at a time and moving babel configuration to newly created .babelrc file but nothing seems to change and the error is still there. Any clues?

Comment: Why did you eject it? Code looks ok and should work (the .babelrc version), in fact it already works in create-react-app

Comment: To be honest I don't remember exactly. I've been working on this project for quite a while and I ejected it long time ago. It's not .babelrc since there's no .babelrc file in create-react-app anymore and babel config is inside package.json.

Comment: Hm maybe that's the issue then, I should think there is better support for .babelrc

Comment: I tried moving babel configuration to .babelrc and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The class(CopyToClipboard) where the error occurs is under **node_modules** folder but you have excluded babel to run on node_modules. It should work if you remove **exclude** option from babel config but I am not sure whether it is the right thing to do.